# HTMLUNIT Add Row in HtmlTable based on table id

Tags: html, htmlunit

Actually , to avoid the jquery stuff, im planning to add the row directly in the table list.

Can you please help me in getting the row added dynamically by setting the values as string in the  htmltable or some other way  (HTMLUNIT).

```
--------------
<table id="list4" class="scroll">
</table>
------------------------
```

---

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomCharacterData;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomNode;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableCell;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;

public class TestMain {

  public static void main(String args[])
        throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    final String htmlContent = "<html><head><title>foo</title></head><body><table id='table1'><tr id='row1'><td>cell1</td></tr><tr id='row2'><td>cell2</td></tr><tr id='row3'><td>cell3</td></tr><tr id='row4'><td>cell4</td></tr><tr id='row5'><td>cell5</td></tr><tr id='row6'><td>cell6</td></tr></table></body></html>";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = loadPage(htmlContent);
    final HtmlTable table = page.getHtmlElementById("list4");
    // want to add to the new row here
    for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
      System.out.println("Found row");
      for (final HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
        System.out.println("   Found cell: " + cell.asText());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did, little modification. It worked for me.

```
    final HtmlTable table = page.getHtmlElementById("highlight");

    HtmlTableRow newRow = (HtmlTableRow) page.createElement("tr");
    HtmlTableCell newCell = (HtmlTableCell) page.createElement("td");
    DomText cellContent =  (DomText) page.createTextNode("Welcome Sireesh");

    newCell.appendChild((org.w3c.dom.Node) cellContent);
    newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    table.appendChild(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code basically create a new row and cell. Then populates the cell with some text, then appends the elements to their parents.

```
HtmlTableRow newRow = page.createElement("tr");
HtmlTableCell newCell = page.createElement("td");
Text cellContent = page.createTextNode("Hello World");
newCell.appendChild(cellContent);
newRow.appendChild(newCell);
table.appendChild(newRow); 
// you can also have `table.insertBefore(newRow, exisitingRow);`
```